# How to continuously keep displaying a timer on django?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a website using django framework and i am kinda new to it. I want to display an item from the database for a specific time on the webpage. I have a custom filter to implement the timer logic , however I am trying to understand that how can I display the actual timer on the page.

Below is the logic for timer :-

```
@register.filter(name="time_left")
def time_left(value):
    t = value - timezone.now()
    days, seconds = t.days, t.seconds
    hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = seconds % 60
    st = str(minutes) + "m " + str(seconds) + "s"
    return st
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost complete with your logic. you just have to pass it to the variable.

views.py

```
@register.filter(name="time_left")
def time_left(value):
    t = value - timezone.now()
    days, seconds = t.days, t.seconds
    hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = seconds % 60
    st = str(minutes) + "m " + str(seconds) + "s"
    context = {"st":st}
    
    return render(request, "template/page.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from .views import time_left

urlpatterns = [
    path('', time_left, name="timeleft")
    ]
```

page.html

```
The Remaining time is {{st}}
```

Comment: use javascript here instead of template_tag.

Comment: Also if you want to display the timer on all pages you should create a ```base.html``` and extend all your sites from this one.

Comment: @harshilsuthar How can we utilize JS here please.

Comment: @coderboy , thanks , now it makes sense to me as a whole.

Comment: @nayak you are welcomed, you should not forget to mark the solution as an answer so others that need help regarding this are directly properly like you were.